# Android DefaultHttpClient() Post Request

Tags: java, android

I want to send a POST request with two parameters from a JsonObject to an python API which response with True or False, but it doesn't work at all...

My Code:

```
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.30.0.47:8080/getsession");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Name", db.getString("name")));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Passwort", db.getString("passwort")));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.v("Response", res.toString());

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```

[LogCat Output: http://pastebin.com/GL54UFGG](http://pastebin.com/GL54UFGG)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your stack trace it clearly states:

```
05-25 20:42:05.455: E/AndroidRuntime(29706): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

This means that you are executing network load in the MainUI thread, You have to use a separate thread for network work, preferably use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).